# OSError: [WinError 6] with undetected chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

```
Exception ignored in: <function Chrome.__del__ at 0x00000241BFF44360>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 769, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 758, in quit
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

The code runs without error through python console and I just wanna know if there is anyway to run the code without running it through the python console. My python version is 3.1.1., Chrome is the lastest version, and undetected chrome driver is also the lastest version.

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl')
```

This is the code that I found from the undetected chromedriver github.

Comment: Same error here. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this problem by modifying code in the
`undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py`.

Go to line 755 and wrap the `time.sleep(0.1)` with `try-except` block
here is how the final code look like

```py
try:
  time.sleep(0.1)
except OSError:
  pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using driver.close() or driver.quit() try changing between them and see if that helps. In my case, I changed it to driver.close() and it works. Python: 3.11

Answer (score 0):

Editing **init**.py fixed it for me.

In normal cases the file **init**.py will be in C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3x\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\

and for me, the time.sleep(0.1) was in line 798.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35714762)